# Экранирование или конвертация URL

Tags: url, конвертация, кодировка, android

Работаю с API Google Maps и API Google Places. В одной из функций для поиска места, адреса формирую правильный get URL и делаю запрос. Так как в поле ввода возможен ввод адреса на русском, необходимо конвертировать все не ASCII символы в стандарт. Я имею ввиду тот стандрат, где пробел - это %20 или %22, кажется. Я думаю, что с такой строкой запрос будет возвращать правильные результаты. Меня интересует, как это сделать на Android. Средствами Java, конечно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если конвертировать только запрос (а не весь адрес), то можно так:

```
URLEncoder.encode("foo bar", "utf-8");
```

Comment: Честно говоря, за это время уже успел сам разобраться, но всё равно спасибо большое!